# Is there a scenario where array_search is faster than a consecutive array_flip and direct lookup?

Tags: php

Imagine you were to search an array of N elements and perform Y Searches on the array values to find the corresponding keys; you can either do Y `array_search`'s or do one `array_flip` and Y direct lookups. Why is the first method alot slower than the second method? Is there a scenario where the first method becomes faster than the second one?
You can assume that keys and values are unique

Comment: That's an interesting question. Do you have any performance tests substantiating this? Additionally, are you using the strict option when doing this check?

Comment: @Daryl Gill why did you edit my question? I actually meant N lookups and N searches, now if I edit it back to the original state all this discussion will be invalid.

Comment: I just one to remark this: `You can assume that keys and values are unique`: This is very important: if values aren't unique, when doing the `array_flip` you will lose some items due to various values will end up in the same key, so latter ones will overwrite former ones.

Comment: btw I think it is a very interesting question, no idea why someone would want to close it.

Comment: @Asad Yes. If you do a simple test it'll show, the speed gap is huge

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Array keys are hashed, so looking them up just requires calling the hash function and indexing into the hash table. So `array_flip()` is O(N) and looking up an array key is O(1), so `Y` searches are O(Y)+O(N).

Array values are not hashed, so searching them requires a linear search. This is O(N), so Y searches are O(N*Y).

Assuming values being searched for are evenly distributed through the array, the average case of linear search has to compare N/2 elements. So `array_flip()` should take about the time of 2 `array_search()` calls, since it has to examine N elements.

There's some extra overhead in creating the hash table. However, PHP uses copy-on-write, so it doesn't have to copy the keys or values during `array_flip()`, so it's not too bad. For a small number of lookups, the first method may be faster. You'd have to benchmark it to find the break-even point.

Comment: I've never *entirely* understood why looking up an array key is constant time, but looking up an array value is linear (assuming both are hashable)?

Comment: @Asad Because the values aren't hashed. You would need yet another hash structure mapping values to value locations.

Comment: Updated my answer to explain this.

Comment: @Corbin I guess that makes sense. I wonder if there is any way to have parallel hash functions, such that both items in each pair can be treated as key or value. Thanks Barmar.

Comment: You could write a class that contains two associative arrays that map in each direction.

Comment: A problem you're likely to run into by flipping an array to speed up searches is clobbering keys from the original array that had the same value. eg $orig = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 1], $flip = [1 => 'c', 2 => 'b']. Was this just a 'what if' sorta question or was there a specific use case you were thinking of?

Comment: @Colin Unless you assign it back to the original array variable, it doesn' clobber anything. If there are duplicate values, it doesn't matter, since all you care about is whether the value exists or not.

Comment: @Barmar the OP mentioned in the question the idea was to perform searches "on the array to find corresponding keys" so in this case keys do matter. The scenario you're describing where you just want to know if a value exists or not, I agree, keys don't matter. Still though, I don't understand why anyone would want to do this.

Comment: @Colin In that case, it only makes sense if values are unique, since `array_search()` only returns one key. If the object is to find the first key if there are dups, the array_flip solution won't work, since it results in the last key.

Comment: @Colin I forgot to mention that you can assume vkeys and values are unique

Comment: Do you think the array can ever get large enough so that method one becomes faster than method two?

Comment: Unlikely, unless most of your matches are very early in the array. If matches are distributed evenly, then on average two linear searches do as much work as one array flip.

Comment: Added some more details about that to the answer.